# PHP Class Return ErrorInfo()

Tags: php, sqlite, class

I have the following class in PHP

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('Database.db');
    }
}
```

and it is called by `$db = new MyDB();`. Is there a way to make `$db->errorInfo()` return the errorInfo() function for databases?

Comment: `errorInfo()` is not a method of the SQLite3 class, as far as I know. Are you thinking of `PDO::errorInfo()`?  The equivalent in SQLite3 is [`SQLite3::lastErrorMsg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lasterrormsg.php) or [`SQLite3::lastErrorCode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lasterrorcode.php).  And when do you want to return it? Do I understand that you want your object `$db` to have an `errorInfo()` method of its own? If so, you would need to write that method.

Comment: You are correct. I am preparing a query and if the result is false, I want it to print the error message

Comment: Post more code if needed, but $db->lastErrorMsg() probably has what you need

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Perfect. If you submit it as answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class extends the [`SQLite3` class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php), but [`errorInfo()` is a method of PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php). The equivalent error reporting mechanisms for `SQLite3` objects are a combination of [`SQLite3::lastErrorMsg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lasterrormsg.php) to display the message text and [`SQLite3::lastErrorCode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lasterrorcode.php).

Given that you have extended the class, those public methods are already available to your `$db` object.

```
echo "SQL error: " . $db->lastErrorMsg();
echo "SQL error code: " . $db->lastErrorCode();
```

`SQLite3` does not have an exact equivalent of `PDO::errorInfo()` returning an **associative array** of error codes and messages however. You just need to call `lastErrorMsg()` or `lastErrorCode()` for the reporting you desire.